# How to get the id of html button through request get parameter in Java?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, mysql

I generate this section through while look in my Jsp Page and I'm assigning restaurant name ids to every button. What I want to do is get the button id when I click the submit button.

```
<section class="content-wrap" id="content">

   <ul>
     <img class="restaurant-logo" src="<%= rs.getString("image") %>"  alt="restaurant image" width="100" height="100" />
     <li> <form id="menuform" action="menu.jsp"><input type="submit" name="restaurantname" id="<%= rs.getString("name") %>" value="Go to Menu" class="main-button" style="float:right; margin-right:6px;"></form><h3><%= rs.getString("name") %> - <%= rs.getString("area") %>, <%= rs.getString("city") %></h3></li>
     <li style="font-style:italic; margin:-15px 0 5px 0;"> <%= rs.getString("cousines") %></li>
     <li style="color:#999; margin-bottom:2px;"> Delivery:</li>
     <li >Free</li>
   </ul>    
</section>
```

See the `menuform`. It has a button on which I click it goes to the menu page. And I want to get the id (which is restaurant name) in my menu page so I can display the menu.

```
<form id="menuform" action="menu.jsp"><input type="submit" name="restaurantname" id="<%= rs.getString("name") %>" value="Go to Menu" class="main-button" style="float:right; margin-right:6px;"></form>
```

If I do `request.getParameter("restaurantname")` in my menu page then it gives me "Go to Menu" which is obvious. What should I do?

Comment: Trying to pass the button id in my menu page. 

id="<%= rs.getString("name") %>"

Comment: I'm doing request.getParameter("restaurantname") in my other menu page which gets "GO TO MENU" instead of the id which is obvious. I'm asking how to get the button id instead

Comment: The button id does not get sent to the server.  You must use the value attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a input, use a button with value.

```
<button type="submit" name="restaurantname" value="<%= rs.getString("name") %>">
    Go to menu
</button>
```

`id`s and `class`es does not get submitted to the server. You could use a script to grab the id and add it to another `input`. But it is unnecessary in your case. `button` value does get submitted with it's form, making it more semantic.

Comment: But it will show the Restaurant name on the button. Can i get anything else through request.getParameter?

Comment: Or is there a way to show "Go to Menu" on the button and value to be different?

Comment: @MuhammadHassam no, the restaurant name does not appear when using button. Only the inner html of it.

Comment: @MuhammadHassam just pass the restaurant name through a hidden form element `<input type="hidden" name="restaurantname" value="<%= rs.getString("name") %>"  />`

Comment: @MuhammadHassam the value attribute is only reused as text for input elements. Button element does not share this behavior.

Comment: Thanks a lot Man! I changed input type to button and it worked awesome! 
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You might check out this tutorial on getting parameters in JSTL:  http://exampledepot.8waytrips.com/egs/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core/getparam.html

You should be able to use `<c:out value="${param.restaurantname}" />` or simply `${param.restaurantname}` which would return the value, "Go to Restaurant".

If you wanted to pass a different value, consider using a hidden input, something like this: `<input type="hidden" name="restaurantname" value="<%= rs.getString("name") %>"  />`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use `Jsoup`, jsoup is a Java library for working with real-world HTML. It provides a very convenient API for extracting and manipulating data, using the best of DOM, CSS, and jquery-like methods.

[Use selector-syntax to find elements in Java](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)

Comment: I'll check it out.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you submit a form, you need an input with value
Please use it

```
<form id="menuform" action="menu.jsp"><input type="submit" name="restaurantname" value="<%= rs.getString("name") %>" placeholder="Go to Menu" class="main-button" style="float:right; margin-right:6px;"></form>
```